# R error: "2 arguments passed to '&' which requires 2"

Tags: r, mpi, hpc

I am running large-scale simulations on a cluster.  The code works mostly fine but occasionally unexpected errors pop up like the one above: "*one node produced an error: 2 arguments passed to '&' which requires 2*".  Does anybody have a clue what this might point to?

**Background**: The code runs in parallel on a cluster using MPI workers, R 3.2.2.  Hence the error messages I see do not include any line numbers nor any further information.  These may also require hundreds of hours of cpu time to replicate.  I have used '&' in my code in two places where it is fed to MPI workers:

```
inRange <- (sim[1] <= nS) & (sim[2] <= nD) & (sim[3] <= nSF) & (sim[4] <= nDF)
```

and

```
  if((S < dim(pr)["S"]) & (D < dim(pr)["D"]) &
     (SF < dim(pr)["SF"]) & (DF < dim(pr)["DF"])) { ...
```

All the variables referred here are computed locally by each MPI worker.
I thought it may be related to MPI communication problems but I just cannot imagine how..

I have wrapped the suspicious pieces of my code into `try()`-blocks but so far I haven't been able to catch anything.  I was also redirecting output to worker-specific files but I am afraid to have too much performance penalty when outputting large amount of debugging information.

Comment: Nothing obvious in the code you posted. That error might be coming from inside other functions you are calling.

Comment: Agree.  I also played with variations the theme like `TRUE & NA`, `TRUE & NULL` etc, but got nothing like this.  I would like to know how it is possible to get this message.  That might give a hint.

Comment: This will do it: `> \`&\`(1,2,3)
Error in \`&\`(1, 2, 3) : 3 arguments passed to \'&\' which requires 2`

Comment: Sure.  But my message told _**2** arguments passed..._